# Downloading files from OneDrive - Selenium

Tags: selenium, download, onedrive

I was trying to download a file from OneDrive through Selenium. But, could not do it. As, in OneDrive we cannot catch the web element(xpath, id) of a specific file, I am unable to download a file from OneDrive through Selenium.

It would be very helpful if anyone can suggest to me some way to download a specific file from OneDrive?

Comment: Add more details to your question, like HTML from which you cant find locators, where exactly you have and issue?

Comment: Here what I got inspecting a specific file in OneDrive:

<img alt="" class="od-ImageTile-image" src="https://am3pap007files.storage.live.com/y4pMmZz9bA2G3WTiFO5rmXBsYO-wGRki38ZyrslvNlaKcOG4x5yYMSySe4H3GCJOK5qcZ1KOa7h8qFqdHLP4n8bJXCgndLkB9Wcckxn8Cbrgqk_Amn1qaIcj2c9PlldTT-Dpd9YY4-ESZoT-zOC2K1VSuftrzN8ZyTZwbqUYfdWuukcksAG5YappXe3QoBZ6BW_24bc_vMfrtfy-JRg0kRAE_MxN-JnTO5AaQCq-uxGdUk/demo.txt?psid=1&amp;width=144&amp;height=2048" style="left: 24.19%; top: 0%; width: 51.61%;">

how would I get the id/xpath of the file and download the file?

Screenshot: 

https://pasteboard.co/JTVQOCn.png